# Get the list of ten top publishers in database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've got following tables in my MySQL database:

> USERS
>
> iduser nick password
>
> ARTICLES
>
> idarticles iduser text

How can I get by one SQL query the list of e.g. 10 top publishers of articles ordering by the count of added articles? Is there any way to do that? I'm using PHP to ask database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this should be quite easy via `JOIN` and `COUNT()`. Something like the following

```
SELECT `users`.`iduser`, COUNT(`articles`.`idarticles`) AS `total_articles`
FROM `users`
INNER JOIN `articles` ON `users`.`iduser` = `articles`.`iduser`
GROUP BY `users`.`iduser`
ORDER BY `total_articles` DESC
LIMIT 10
```

A little explaining:

- `COUNT()` will get you what it says - a count of all relevant entries in `articles`
- `INNER JOIN` will pair all entries that belong together (defined via `ON`)
- `GROUP BY` tells SQL that you are interested in various results, each differing by `iduser` (without this, you'd get all articles counted in the first returned row)
- `ORDER BY .. DESC` is important to get the result in a descending order (so most published first)
- `LIMIT 10` does exactly that

Comment: And I will return the table, which contains user-id and count of articles?

Comment: Yes it should. See my update, ofc you need `COUNT()` (3 articles => 3) and not `SUM()` (articleid 1, articleid 4, articleid 7 => 12 and not 3)

Comment: The previous code was a bit flawed, I've updated it (again, d'oh!) and added a little explanation. You're welcome!

Comment: Your answer was really helpful for me. Thank you also for explantation!